# Filtering posts list table

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, admin

My post_type is `'part'`. I created a custom field `'Images'` this way (simply added new columns to the array):

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-part_columns', 'my_columns_filter' );
function my_columns_filter( $columns ) {
    unset( $columns['comments'] );
    $column_attach = array( 'images' => 'Images' );
    $column_content = array( 'content' => 'Content' );
    $columns = array_slice( $columns, 0, 5, true ) + $column_attach + 
        array_slice( $columns, 5, NULL, true );
    $columns = array_slice( $columns, 0, 6, true ) + $column_content + 
        array_slice( $columns, 6, NULL, true );
    return $columns;
}
```

Added content to them (check if there are any images):

```
add_action( 'manage_part_posts_custom_column', 'my_column_action' );
function my_column_action( $column ) {
    global $post;    
    if ( $column === 'images' ){
        $images = get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );
        if ( count( $images ) > 0 ){
            echo 'YES';
        }
        else { echo 'NO'; }
    }
}
```

Created select entry:

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'img_part_filtering' );
function img_part_filtering() {    
    global $typenow ;    
    if ( $typenow == 'part' ) {
        $selected_now = '';
        if ( isset( $_GET['filter-img'] ) ) {
            $selected_now = esc_attr( $_GET['filter-img'] );
        }
        echo '<select name="filter-img" id="filter-img">';
        echo '<option value="" >' . __( 'Images', 'filter-img' ) . '</option>';
        echo '<option value="yes" ' . selected( $selected_now, 'yes', false ) . 
            '>' . __( 'YES', 'filter-img' ) . '</option>';
        echo '<option value="no" ' . selected( $selected_now, 'no', false ) . 
            '>' . __( 'NO', 'filter-img' ) . '</option>';
        echo '</select>';
    }
}
```

How can I filter admin posts list by the `'images'` column? I have tried:

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'img_query_filtering' );
function img_query_filtering( $query ) {    
    global $pagenow;
    $qv = &$query->query_vars;   
    if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && 
        isset( $q_vars['post_type'] ) && 
        $q_vars['post_type'] == 'part' &&
        isset( $q_vars['filter-img'] ) )
    {
        if ( ! isset( $qv['meta_query'] ) ) {
            $qv['meta_query'] = array();
        }
        if ( ! empty( $_GET['filter-img'] ) ) {
            if ('yes' == $_GET['filter-img'] ) {
                $qv['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'field'   => 'images',
                    'value'   => 'YES',
                    'compare' => '=',
                    'type'    => 'CHAR'
                );
            }
            if ('no' == $_GET['filter-img'] ) {
                $qv['meta_query'][] = array(
                    'field'   => 'images',
                    'value'   => 'NO',
                    'compare' => '=',
                    'type'    => 'CHAR'
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried just to check its operability for my purposes, but it is not working:

```
function posts_where( $where ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        global $pagenow;
        if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && 
            isset( $q_vars['post_type'] ) && 
            $q_vars['post_type'] == 'part' &&
            isset( $q_vars['filter-img'] ) ) 
        {
            $where .= ' AND 1=0';
        }
    }
    return $where;
}
```

Is there a way to add such column and filter by it?